# Theater.js not working on page loaded with Angular ui route

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make [Theater.JS](https://github.com/Zhouzi/TheaterJS) work with Angular application.

If Div in which TheaterJS is supposed to insert dynamically typed contents is on the index page, it works perfectly fine.

But if I keep the same div on the page which is loaded using ui-view  (or using ng-view for that matter), TheaterJs throws following exception

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

I understand its happening because TheaterJs is loaded before main.html page is loaded through ui-view. But I am not sure how to handle this scenario.

Here is the [plnkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/4XmWVTwbVXgGtpBImyOs?p=preview) with the example. The TheaterJS works when div is on index page but fails to work when the div is on main.html which is loaded dynamically using ui-view.

In my project, I want to use TheaterJS on a page loaded using ui-view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By placing the script include into the `<head>` and moving the call to `new TheaterJS()` into a directive, you are able to use it in your partials.

Here is a plunker showing your working template:

http://plnkr.co/edit/JAbSmNOAZtUMkc976sh8?p=preview

Directive:

```
app.directive("theaterDirective", function() {
  return {
    link: function () {
      var theater = new TheaterJS();
      theater.describe("text", {speed: .7, accuracy: .7}, "#text");
      theater.write("text:It now works in template partials", 600);
      theater.write("text:It is no longer restricted to the Index page", 600);
      theater.write(function () { theater.play(true); }); 

    }
  }
})
```

HTML partial:

```
<h1>This is main.html page content</h1>
<h1 theater-directive id="text"><noscript></noscript></h1>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Yes it works great with link function. Thanks for the prompt help :)